# Upload Excel using nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, excel, csv, xls

I am uploading an Excel file and inserting into a mysql table. My code is working with Linux. But I want it should run with other also so I am predicting that Xls is not working.

How to change into CSV or any other way so we can upload the Excel or csv which support any version?

```
function getfileDetails(req, res) {
    var sampleFile, fileInfo = {};
        var date1=new Date();
         var currdatetime = date1.getFullYear()+"-"+(date1.getMonth()+1)+"-"+date1.getDate()+" "+date1.getHours()+":"+date1.getMinutes()+":"+date1.getSeconds();
        console.log(currdatetime);
    var MyData = [];
            if (!req.files) {
            res.send('No files were uploaded.');
            return;
          }   
          sampleFile = req.files.fileInputXLSX1;

        var datetimestamp = Date.now();

          console.log("Uploaded -- ",sampleFile);
          var fileExtn = sampleFile.name.split(".").pop();
          var extractedFilename = sampleFile.name.slice(0, sampleFile.name.lastIndexOf('.'));
          var userid=req.headers['userid'];
          var uploadFileName = extractedFilename+'_'+userid+'_'+datetimestamp+'.'+fileExtn;

          console.log("uploadFileName -- ",uploadFileName);
          fileInfo = {
            "name": uploadFileName,
            "mimetype": sampleFile.mimetype
          }
          // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server  
          sampleFile.mv(__dirname+'/Details/'+uploadFileName, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                var parseXlsx = require('excel');
                parseXlsx(__dirname+'/Details/'+uploadFileName, function(err, data) {
                    if(err) throw err;          
                    // data is an array of arrays
                    else{
                        if(data!=null)
                    {
                        var queryString= "Truncate table `details`;"
                        connection.query(queryString, function(err,result){
                                        if(err) { 
                                            res.write(JSON.stringify(err));
                                                res.end();
                                                } else {
                                                    res.send('File uploaded!');
                                                        }
                                                });
                    }
                            for (var index = 1; index < data.length; index++) 
                            {
                                MyData.push(data[index][0],data[index][1],data[index][2],data[index][3], data[index][4], data[index][5],data[index][6],data[index][7],data[index][8],data[index][9]);
                                var queryString="INSERT INTO `details`(name,tname,fname,timestamp) VALUES ('"+data[index][0]+"','"+data[index][1]+"','"+data[index][2]+"','"+currdatetime+"')";
                                    connection.query(queryString, function(err,result){
                                        if(err) { 
                                            res.write(JSON.stringify(err));
                                                res.end();
                                                } else {
                                                    res.send('File uploaded!');
                                                        }
                                                });
                            }   

                        }
                });         
         if(err) {
           res.status(500);
            res.send(err);
               }
        });

}
```

Please help ,I am New in Node.

Answer (score 1):

hey can you try [json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv) npm module. this will solve you problem @TB.M

Answer (score 0):

## This code is working fine, try this..

```
var xlsx = require('node-xlsx');
    var fs = require('fs');
    var obj = xlsx.parse(__dirname + '/new.xls'); // parses a file
    var rows = [];
    var writeStr = "";

    //looping through all datarow
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
    {
        var dataRow = obj[i];
        //loop through all rows in the sheet
        for(var j = 0; j < dataRow['data'].length; j++)
        {
                //add the row to the rows array
                rows.push(dataRow['data'][j]);
        }
    }

    //creates the csv string to write it to a file
    for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
    {
        writeStr = writeStr + rows[i].join(",") + "\n";
    }

    //writes to a file, but you will presumably send the csv as a      
    //response instead
    fs.writeFile(__dirname + "/data.csv", writeStr, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("data.csv was saved in the current directory!");
    });
```

Comment: install node-xlsx with npm  
npm install node-xlsx

Then use it with your excel file.

Comment: i m trying but in mycode its not giving proper output..can u come on chat?

Comment: No right now I am busy please don't mind, we can talk after 5 hours.

Comment: Check it doesn't handle commas in the values, you'll need to add double quotes and escape values containing double-quotes

Comment: In questions i have given my code.In that i need to add yours. how i should add given code.That is not happening.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164685/discussion-between-tb-m-and-radhey-shyam).